# Extend the strategy pattern: Add Context methods and subclasses

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, strategy-pattern

> The [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) defines a family of algorithms, encapsulates each
>   one, and makes them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary
>   independently from clients that use it.

Very nice indeed. But consider this situation: I have a strategy pattern with a few subclasses of context and a few algorithms, as shown below. The code should be closed for modification in the end, but I still need to be able to achieve the following extensibilities. Without changes to existing code:

1. Add new methods to `Context` that use Strategy
2. Add new subtypes of `Context`

[image: Strategy pattern diagram]

I thought of [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), which is good for achieving 1). But adding new `Context` subtypes would require changes in all `Visitor`s, so this doesn't work.

What about [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)? By decorating `Context` you could add new methods. But what I really need is to add methods with concrete implementations that can vary like in the strategy pattern.

What do you think, how can this be achieved?

Best regards

richn

**EDIT:**

This is a concrete example. 
[image]

I should explain: I have an application with a simulation window showing different kinds of `VisibleObject`s and another window to control these objects. 
The state of the `VisibleObject`s needs to be reflected in the simulation using strategy. For example, if I disable a `Polygon`, it should be hidden in the simulation, or completely removed, depending on it's concrete `DisablingBehavior`.

If a new kind of `VisibleObject`, say a `Picture` is defined, I want all the existing `DisablingBehaviors` and `PositioningBehaviors` to be able to deal with it.

And if there is a new operation, say `MirrorObject()`, that needs to be carried out on `VisibleObjects` I want to be able to define different `MirroringBehaviors` behaviors like `AxisMirroring` or `PointMirroring` and assign them to `VisibleObject`s.

Comment: Please give a concrete example.

Comment: @jhauffin, I added a concrete example in my post. Do you need any more details?

Comment: Why is it that you think your current design cannot acheive your objectives?  It looks to me that you can drop in a `PictureObject` that is a subclass of `VisibleObject` and it should be able to be passed to your `DisablingBehavior` and `PositioningBehavior` subclasses without any issue.

Comment: Yes, adding new subclasses is easy but I wouldn't know how to add new methods.

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns doesn't cover all situations. You should not blindly follow some pattern, or try to fit you software to match some pattern. Here is the quote from Robert C. Martin book:

> Often, they were presented without showing how the code evolved to use
>   the pattern. This might give you the idea that patterns are simply
>   something you insert into your code and designs in completed form.
>   This is not what I advise. Rather, I prefer to evolve the code I am
>   working on in the direction of a pattern. I may get to the pattern, or
>   I may not.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you might need here is a Bridge pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern.

It's not going "protect" you from adding new methods. I pretty certain no pattern can help in this case. When you're adding public methods to interfaces and/or base classes, you're modifying (not extending!) essential contracts with all the consequences.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this and get back to you.